# Can you leave chicken in smoker after it quits cooking to stay warm

Tags: chicken

Can you leave chicken in the smoker after it has stopped cooking to keep it warm?

Comment: What kind of smoker? Is there still smoke? What temperature? How long do you want to leave it?

Comment: Master built, no smoke, had to cook it at 225, and I want to leave it about to 3 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Safety-wise, as long as you keep the chicken above 140°F, you can keep it there forever. Once you get below 140°F, you're supposed to have it either eaten or cooled to 40°F within 2 hours. (It's actually safe a little lower—but it's best to leave a margin of error!) For details, see [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Quality-wise, it's going to continue to cook, and its going to continue to lose moisture (unless your smoker is really humid, like a commercial combi oven can be). The hotter it is, the faster it will cook and dry out. Cooking is fairly slow once you get down to near 140°F, though.

Three hours should be doable.